# Webdriver's click() method not working on a website

Tags: webdriver

I am using WebDriver API to test a webpage and the `click()` method is not working on a particular webpage.

Neither it is showing any exception nor clicking on the webelement (a link in my case). I tried to find the element using xpath, id and link but the click did not work.

However, when I tried `contextClick` (i.e. right click) operation on the same link, it worked. Also when I print the text or `tagName` of the web-element, the text or tagName is displayed perfectly fine on the output screen.

**My code:**

```
WebDriver browser=new InternetExplorerDriver();
browser.get("some website");
WebElement linkkk=browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topsort']/li[2]/a"));
linkkk.click();
```

**web-page code:**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="blind" style="display: none;"></div>
    <ul id="topsort">
      <li>something</li>
      <li><a class="category_nav_remote_link selected" href="some website">some text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I even used:**

```
Actions action=new Actions(browser);<br/>
action.click(linkkk);
action.perform();
```

**But in vain.**

Answer (score 7):

Try below options:

```
WebElement linkkk=browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topsort']/li[2]/a"));
linkkk.click();
//click once again
linkkk.click();
```

OR - Try by sending ENTER key as below:

```
linkkk.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

OR - First move to that link & then click or send ENTER key

```
Actions moveTo = new Actions(driver);
moveTo.moveToElement(linkkk).click().perform();
```

Comment: I am still looking an answer to this. We cannot user Action class for Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Try using IJavaScriptExecutor to click on the button. It's been very successful on my app.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver).ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0].click()",webElement);
```